# Fill a UIBezierPath shape with stripes

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I have a class that draws a circle inside of a view. I know how to fill the circle, and I know how to have the circle only be an outline.

I want to fill the circle with stripes, so that the below circle would look like the outline with alternating stripes of red and white, but the white stripes would only look white against a white background because they would represent the lack a colour fill.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class Circle: UIView{
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect){
        let radius = bounds.width / 4
        let centerY = (bounds.maxY - bounds.minY) / 2
        let centerX = (bounds.maxX - bounds.minX)/2
        let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)
        drawCircle(radius: radius, center: centerPoint)

    }

    private func drawCircle(radius: CGFloat, center: CGPoint){
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2*CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        path.close()
        UIColor.red.set()
        path.lineWidth = 5.0
        path.stroke()
        //path.fill()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution using [clipping regions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath/1624341-addclip)

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class Circle: UIView{
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect){
        let radius = bounds.width / 4
        let centerY = (bounds.maxY - bounds.minY) / 2
        let centerX = (bounds.maxX - bounds.minX)/2
        let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)
        drawCircle(radius: radius, center: centerPoint)
    }
    
    private func drawCircle(radius: CGFloat, center: CGPoint){
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.addArc(withCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2*CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        path.close()
        UIColor.red.set()
        path.lineWidth = 5.0

        //////////////////////////The part the produces stripes ////////////////////
        let bounds = path.bounds
        
        let stripes = UIBezierPath()
        for x in stride(from: 0, to: bounds.size.width, by: 20){
            stripes.move(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + x, y: bounds.origin.y ))
            stripes.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x + x, y: bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height ))
        }
        stripes.lineWidth = 10

        path.addClip()
        stripes.stroke()        
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        path.stroke()
    }
}
```

[image]